# Error unset value from array in php

Tags: php

I want unset all value from this array, but result only remove half

```
Ex 1:
$filter = array("English", "Malay", "Student Pass", "NRIC");
for($i=0; $i<count($filter); $i++){
    unset($filter[$i]);
}
print_r($filter);
```

=> Result `Array ( [2] => Student Pass [3] => NRIC )`

```
Ex 2:
$filter = array("English", "Malay");
for($i=0; $i<count($filter); $i++){
    unset($filter[$i]);
}
print_r($filter);
```

=> Result `Array ( [1] => Malay )`

Comment: Why not overwrite it with an empty array: `$filter = array();`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that every time your for loop runs, it recalculates the array's length with `count($filter)`. Thus, the for loop runs less often than there are elements within the array. Instead you should determine the array's length **ahead** of the loop and only use this variable within the loop:

e.g.:

```
<?
    $filter = array("English", "Malay", "Student Pass", "NRIC");
    $arrayLength = count($filter); // contains the initial length of the array
    for($i=0; $i<$arrayLength;$i++) {
        unset($filter[$i]);
    }
    print_r($filter);
?>
```

However, regarding overall performance it might be better to *overwrite* the array or even [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it.

e.g.:

```
// Overwrite it with an empty array
$filter = array();

// Unset it
unset($filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you unset the item on the array it removes it. So on the next iteration the count($filter) has now gone down. You could do as @Daan suggested and just set $filter = array(). However if you insisted on calling unset you should loop over the array in reverse order.

```
for($i = count($filter) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    unset($filter[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you `unset` an element, `count($filter)` decreases. Let me give you an example:

You have six apples. You are eating the n'th apple while n is smaller than the number of apples. So, you eat the 0'th apple, because 0 < 6. You have 5 apples. You eat the 1st apple, because 1 < 5. You have 4 apples. You eat the 2nd apple, because 2 < 4. You have 3 apples. You don't eat the 3rd apple, since 3 < 3 is not true. As a result, three apples will remain. Your mistake was assuming that the ever incremented `index` is slower than the ever decremented `count` if and only if the array is not empty. This is wrong and you need a different approach, like this:

```
while (count($filter) > 0) {
   unset($filter[count($filter) - 1]);
}
```

This is sub-optimal though, just unset the array instead, like this:

```
unset($filter);
```